# Coding Issues faced in Andrew Ng's course

Tags: machine-learning, homework

I was going through Andrew's ML course on Coursera (Week 2).
I attach with this post some snaps of my codes for the optional exercise part (of the programming assignment problems) for that week, namely, the codes for **featureNormalize.m** (4th image from top), **computeCostMulti.m** (2nd image from top), and **gradientDescentMulti.m** (3rd image from top), along with the outputs (1st image) that I obtained on submission, and a figure depicting the convergence of gradient descent (last image). Is something wrong with the codes for featureNormalize.m and gradientDescentMulti.m? I haven't received any feedback for these two, and I don't know what's that supposed to mean. (I haven't tried Normal Equations yet, so that one's ok).

P.S, I know that it is very stupid of me to post such a specific question on this platform, but I need an answer to it, and I can't post the codes on the User's Discussion Forum for the course on Coursera, for that violates the platform's Honor-Code.

[image: Output:]

[image: computeCostMulti.m]

[image: gradientDescentMulti.m]

[image: featureNormalize.m]

[image: Convergence of gradient descent]

Comment: I STRONGLY Recommend you to use the course forums (I did the course too!), as they are really good for these kind of problems, people are really helpful and, although stackexchange is a great site, I think that your case can be handled better in the course forums.

Comment: The purpose here seems to be to get around restrictions on posting code, but that's what is done here. It's more on topic in the course forum and is a "why isn't this code working" question, which are generally closed on SO.

Comment: Thanks. I just wasn't sure whether the forum was a suitable place for this. Now I know better :)

Comment: Mentor: "Posting solution code is a violation of the Honor Code.

In general, if you see “Nice Work!” for 0/0 ungraded assignments then the grader accepted your solution. If you don’t it didn’t.

I suggest you use the ex1 test cases in the Resources section to debug. I also suggest you read the tutorials, also in the Resources section, for this assignment. "

Comment: Me: "My apologies. I had previously posted this question on Data-Science stackexchange, for I was aware that posting code here might violate Honor Code, but the people there urged me to come to this forum instead. :)

But the test-cases help. Thanks!"

Comment: Mentor: "Please comment on that forum that posting your code here violates the Honor Code but that help was available without doing that.

Let them know that this is the right place but descriptions should be limited to symptoms of the problem and error messages, if any. That will better prepare the next people they advise.

BTW, posting your solution code on a public forum like Stack Exchange or GitHub is also a violation of the Honor Code. "

Comment: Btw, I just had to replace a '1' by 'i' in one of the loops in featureNormalize.m. A silly mistake.